# Can I use "redirect.regex" and "redirect.replacement"? to redirect from mysite.com to my-site.com?

Tags: traefik

I'm trying to redirect all traffic from mysite.com to my-site.com. I'd like to do this with Traefik, if possible.

```
    - traefik.frontend.redirect.regex=^https?://(?:www.)?.mysite.([a-z.]+)
    - traefik.frontend.redirect.replacement=https://www.my-site.$$1
    - traefik.frontend.rule=HostRegexp:www.my-site.{tld:[a-z.]+}
```

The documentation for `redirect.regex` and `redirect.replacement` is a little unclear to me :

> Redirects to another URL to this frontend.

Before a match (`redirect.regex`) is made, do I still need to match the request with `rule` first - in order to qualify that request to be tested against `redirect.regex`?

Is what I am trying to achieve doable with `regex` and `replacement`?